# Running a Docker plugin (scout), in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, docker, azure-pipelines

I would like to run the [docker scout](https://docs.docker.com/scout/) command from a Docker task in azure, so that I don't have to use my private registry credentials to authenticate myself, but only use the Docker task for login.

I've seen that [Docker@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v0?view=azure-pipelines) allows launching custom docker commands, e.g. `docker images` becomes

```yaml
    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Show Docker images'
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'my_container_registry'
        action: 'Run a Docker command'
        customCommand: images     # here 'docker' before the customCommand is run implicitly
```

Thus in my case it would be

```yaml
    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Run Docker Scout'
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'my_container_registry'
        action: 'Run a Docker command'
        customCommand: scout my_img:my_tag   # here 'docker' before the customCommand is run implicitly
```

my problem is:

- If I run this command, docker scout is not found (it's a plugin to install).
- If I install docker scout from CLI, it is still not found by the command in Docker@0 (I think because it is an isolated runtime).
  So I wonder how I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Docker Scout integration guide for Microsoft Azure DevOps Pipelines https://docs.docker.com/scout/integrations/ci/azure/ ?

The issue you're encountering could indeed stem from the isolated runtime environment within the Docker task, which may not have the necessary dependencies or configurations to locate and execute the docker scout command.

Docker Scout team has provided a comprehensive example tailored for Azure DevOps-connected repositories, encompassing Docker image definitions and content. This pipeline is activated by a main branch commit, orchestrating image building and leveraging Docker Scout to generate a CVE report. This integration offers robust insights into security vulnerabilities.

Before running the docker scout command, you could include additional steps to install the required dependencies or plugins within the Docker task itself. This would ensure that the required tools are available within the isolated runtime. For example:

```
stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build image
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build an image
            inputs:
              command: build
              dockerfile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile"
              repository: $(image)
              tags: |
                $(tag)
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: Find CVEs on image
            inputs:
              script: |
                # Install the Docker Scout CLI
                curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/scout-cli/main/install.sh | sh -s --
                # Login to Docker Hub required for Docker Scout CLI
                docker login -u $(DOCKER_HUB_USER) -p $(DOCKER_HUB_PAT)
                # Get a CVE report for the built image and fail the pipeline when critical or high CVEs are detected
                docker scout cves $(image):$(tag) --exit-code --only-severity critical,high
```

Comment: yes, I had seen that, but I wanted to avoid passing credentials. I was hoping there was a way to take advantage of Docker login via task. Thank you for the response.